# Accleration and frequency

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics

Recently, I was taught by my teacher that the acceleration of an electron in a Bohr Atom is equal to its frequency.  I am confused and did not understand  why it turns out to be equal.

Comment: acceleration=v^2/r but angular frequency=v/r. Can you give some reference where you got that?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: it isn't. You can tell this simply by the dimensions of the two quantities. Frequency has dimensions of inverse time, acceleration has dimensions of length $\times$ inverse time$^2$. There is however an easy relation between the acceleration of such an electron and the frequency of its orbit, and indeed this works for any object executing circular motion. The centripetal acceleration $a_c$ is given by $\frac{v^2}{r}$, and with the angular frequency $\omega = v/r$ we can rewrite this as $a_c = \omega^2 r$. If you want to use the frequency instead of the angular frequency then simply substitute $\omega = 2\pi f$.

Comment: Oh, While I was solving a Problem and when a problem stated to calculate acceleration of electron, A sir told us that in Hydrogen , Acceleration can be treated equal to frequency of electron

Comment: Well that sir is wrong.